# Installing Gitea on Windows Server 2012 or later

Tags: git, gitea

Is it possible to install [Gitea](https://gitea.io) on Windows Server 2012 or later? I could not see any specific instructions, with nearly all documentation covering a *nix host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering gitea proposes a Windows binary (see for instance [dl.gitea.io/gitea/1.2.1/](https://dl.gitea.io/gitea/1.2.1/) or [`github.com/go-gitea/gitea/releases`](https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea/releases)), then yes, you can run it on a Windows machine:

- [gitea-1.2.1-windows-4.0-386.exe](https://dl.gitea.io/gitea/1.2.1/gitea-1.2.1-windows-4.0-386.exe)
- [gitea-1.2.1-windows-4.0-amd64.exe](https://dl.gitea.io/gitea/1.2.1/gitea-1.2.1-windows-4.0-amd64.exe)

Comment: omg! u have a million reputation..is your job is to answer for the stack questions only ?lol

Comment: @jayaprakashR no, just a few questions per day. But [every day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122976/6309) for 14 years: it adds up.

Comment: nice contribution to the community @VonC am inspired. I am new t the IT field and start my creere as devops and sure i ll also contribute more once i get enough knowledge

Comment: @jayaprakashR Great! Good luck to you :)

Answer (score 0):

[Download and install](https://golang.org/dl/) GO language. (It’s as easy as next-next-finish)

Open a command prompt and type:

```
mkdir %GOPATH%
cd %GOPATH%
go get -d -u code.gitea.io/gitea
cd "%GOPATH%/src/code.gitea.io/gitea"
go build
```

> Optional: copy this gitea folder to some other folder (e.g. C:\gitea)
>   if you don’t want to run this from your %GOPATH% folder

```
.\gitea web
```

> launch http://localhost:3000

Click "sign in" to configure initial configuration (I suggest to use `mysql`)

if you want to use `mysql`  i suggest to use `xampp`